# Main menu in included php file

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on twitter-bootstrap based website, and decided to keep header and footer as separate php files included in each sub-page of the website. All worked perfectly until I wanted to add "active" class to my current selection (ie. page that user is currently on).

I have found this script that should work fine:

```
$("a").click(function() {        
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent("div").addClass("active");
});
```

but I realised it works only for split second and than we're back to default-nothing-selected menu. I checked the page html and class was not added. I realised it's because after redirecting to new url, new header.php is being loaded - therefore no selection is applied.

Any advice on how can I get around it?

Comment: What does your full rendered HTML look like? It's possible you're missing something in the markup.

Comment: You should be able to know which page you're on in PHP. Then just check and add the class inline in PHP.

Comment: Rendered html doesn't include class="active" though, probably because whole site is reloaded and hearder.php starts off fresh.

The website address is changing properly: name/index.php or name/about.php, but menu is loaded everytime from header.php (above js script is located in header.php file). What do you mean by "adding the class inline in PHP"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what is being returned from the server global by just doing a test like this:

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

Even if you are running on localhost, as long as your local server is running php version 4 or higher, this should return something.

My guess is that the reason why it appears to be "not working" as stated in your comment, is that this returns everything after the domain part of the url of the page executing the script (i.e., not your include but the actual page that will be returned to the user). So for example, **http://example.com/foo/bar.php** would return **/foo/bar.php**.  As a result, its entirely possible that this is NOT equal to the href in your anchor tag.  For example, if you're linking to a page /foo/bar.php from foo/foo.php, you could use a relative path like href="bar.php".  So, if you check whether $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is equal to the link href, they won't be equal even if it's the same page.  Make sense?

### How I would do this in PHP:

You don't show the structure of your site or your html so this example just assumes that there are 2 pages (index.php and contact.php) which are both in the root folder of the server.  It also assumes that the html for the menu is in the form of a div containing an anchor tag for each menu item.

```
<?php
$currentpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$home = "index.php";
$contact = "contact.php";
?>

<div class="col-sm-2<?php echo ($currentpage == '/'.$home) ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $home; ?>">Home</a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2<?php echo ($currentpage == '/'.$contact) ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo $contact; ?>">Contact</a>
</div>
```

So, what does this do?

First there are some variables: one for the $currentpage using the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], and one each for page link in my menu.

Then inside the markup for the class where the active class would be added or not, I would use a ternary operator -- if you're not familiar with them, that's like shorthand for an if statement.  The syntax for this looks like: (*the thing to check for true*) ? *what to do if it's true* : *what to do if it's **not** true*;.

In this case, I'm comparing the $currentpage value with the value of the $home variable preceded by a forward slash (so it matches how the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] returns the page path).  If it's true, I echo out a space plus the word active.  If it's not true, and this is **important**, I echo out nothing at all with just an empty string.  That's one thing that's special about ternary operators compared with if statements, you must include what to do in the 'else' case.

That's pretty much all there is.  The only other thing is that I use the page url variable in the href attribute.

Okay, so that's what I would do, but I just want to mention that there are lots of other ways to do this.  For example, you could do sort of the same thing in javascript or jQuery.  In that case you'd just include a script on every page that uses window.location.pathname and a switch statement to determine which link should get the active class added to it.

Comment: Thank you my friend, the issue was what you mentioned in the first part of your response, I was simply putting /index.php instead of entire path, and that's why it didn't work. Pasting whole path, with all subfolders from the main domain did the trick. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution for this kind of scenario.
Whenever you are rendering the page, include a flag name for that page
and use that flag condition in your header file,

For e.g. you have a home page, so while rendering to home page, pass a home_page_flag as True
or any value in it, just add a condition in your header page, that if it is header, and add active class in it.

```
<ul>
  <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '[this_link]') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?>>
    <a href="[this_link]">Home</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

<del>Syntax may be wrong, as i am not a PHP guy, which this login should work in any language</del> <sup><sub>fixed by your friendly neighborhood PHP guy - please change out instances of `[this_link]` with your actual href text</sub></sup>

Comment: If you changed '[this_link]' to a variable -- it'd be easier to maintain and less to type.  For example, var $home = 'index.php'; Then you could use $home in both your if statement and your href attribute.

Comment: Thanks guys, but 2 problems with that. 
First - I need to insert 'active' class to existing class: <div class="col-sm-2 ...active..."> 

Second - $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] doesn't seem to be working (nothing gets inserted). I'm running on localhost, could that be a reason?